# Save export settings in Media Encoder

Tags: premiere, adobe-media-encoder

I have an hour+ project in Premiere Pro that is a live performance of a musical group.  I've broken it up via Markers into 15 songs.  I then, mostly with a lot of "by hand", exported the 15 songs to Media Encoder and it produced 15 videos.  The catch is, the project is "mostly" done but I will likely want to go back and tweak things here and there.

Is there a way to save the 15 export settings as a single unit?  They are all exactly the same except for the in and out points and the output file name.  Or... perhaps there is some type of automation that I can use with Media Encoder so I can have an external "script" that would fire up the exports.

If I right click on one of the jobs in the queue (that has completed), "Export Settings" is disabled.  Perhaps that is what I'm looking for?

Really, utopia would be if I could select a marker and say "Export" and it would pick up the title from the marker as well as the in and out points (i.e. the work area).

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.

You could nest each section from your master timeline into it's own timeline, from the in and out points of where your start marker to your next would be.

That is the only thing I could think of. You could still work off the master timeline provided you dont do any time shifts / move any content up or down the timeline.

Then you could batch out the sequences to AME and apply the pre-set to all of them at once for export.

Comment: "nest" ... that sounds interesting.  I will look into how to nest time lines given the state I'm already in.  Indeed, I was somewhat wondering how I was going to create the final end to end video and making it a sequence of the smaller sequences seems like a good approach.  Any pointers on how to nest things given I've already done a lot of work would be awesome.

Comment: Late to reply. But to best a sequence in PPro or a Composition in AE simply either drag the sequence/composition from your Project Panel into a different sequence/composition or right click the sequence and “Create New Sequence/Composition from Clip”

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, I believe what you are looking for is the presets. You can adjust all of the settings to be exactly how you want them, then click on the 'Save Preset' button located here:

[image]

Then when you are in the Queue, you can select as many exports as you want and update the Preset dropdown and all of them will be exaclty as you wish.